# docker-compose: error while trying to install MDBoostrap Pro with oauth authentication

Tags: angular, docker, npm, docker-compose, mdbootstrap

I'm trying to deploy and application developed with MDBootstrap Pro which is installed via npm + oauth2 authentication.
Basically, into dir project, in order to install it you have to run the following command:

```
npm install git+https://oauth2:YOUR_TOKEN@git.mdbootstrap.com/mdb/angular/ng-uikit-pro-standard.git --save
```

It works fine, until you have to put your project into a container.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:13.10-alpine AS builder
COPY ./ ./portal/
WORKDIR /portal
RUN npm i
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod

FROM httpd:2.4
COPY --from=builder /portal/dist/InternationalItaly/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

When the build reaches the line `RUN npm i`, it crashes for this reason:

```
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://oauth2:TOUR_TOKEN@git.mdbootstrap.com/mdb/angular/ng-uikit-pro-standard.git
```

I tried to install it before the `npm i`, but the problem seems to be not solved. I don't want to import it as a huge asset (basically, cloning the repo into the assets of my project), i would like to implement it as a npm dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to install `git`

Try this:

```
FROM node:13.10-alpine AS builder
RUN apk add --no-cache git
COPY ./ ./portal/
WORKDIR /portal
RUN npm i
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod

FROM httpd:2.4
COPY --from=builder /portal/dist/InternationalItaly/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

Personally I prefer the `git+ssh://...`

An Example:

```
ARG KNOWN_HOSTS
ARG ID_RSA

RUN apk add --no-cache git openssh
RUN mkdir ~/.ssh && echo $KNOWN_HOSTS >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts && echo -en $ID_RSA >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN mv ssh_config ~/.ssh/ssh_config
```

Hope this helps